# SQL Script Needs improvements, Could use some tips

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery

I recently got a test to figure out how to optimize this SQL Script, I have never made a script, and only create queries to get data at my work. This is the Script.

The tables have valid data and joins, the @GUID is already declared and has NVARCHAR values.

This is the SQL script

I am pretty new to this, I need to optimize this script, and from what I know, its better to Join the query instead of using Sub-queries. (correct me if I am wrong)
From What I understand from this script, it is asking information from 2 different Databases

CUSTOMER_CARDNUMBER and PROFILE

I can't see the information in these Fake databases, but that is not part of this test.

In these databases it is asking for multiple information GENERATED_CARDNUMBER, and CUSTOMER_CARDNUMBER with the values = @GUID (which I don't completely understand)

IT WIll Begin a Update if the REVISION_Status = A, if GUID = @GUID what I understand this Script is looking for in both databases. and If it does not find it, it will set a REVISION_STATUS with a Date if the query does not find GUID = @GUID; ( Please correct me if wrong)

I could use help, in improving this script, how and why.. even if there are little mistakes.

Thanks!!

```
IF EXISTS
(

    SELECT *
    FROM   CUSTOMER_CARDNUMBER
    WHERE  GENERATED_CARDNUMBER IN
    (
        SELECT CARDNUMBER
        FROM   Profile
        WHERE  Cardnumber IN
        (
            SELECT GENERATED_CARDNUMBER
            FROM   CUSTOMER_CARDNUMBER
            WHERE  CUSTOMER_CARDNUMBER = @GUID
        )
    )
)
BEGIN
    UPDATE GUID_ACTION
      SET  
          REVISION_STATUS = 'A', 
          REVISION_DATE_CREATED = GETDATE()
    WHERE  GUID = @GUID;
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
    UPDATE GUID_ACTION
      SET  
          REVISION_STATUS = 'F', 
          REVISION_DATE_CREATED = GETDATE()
    WHERE  GUID = @GUID;
END;
```

Comment: Changing the `IN` to a `JOIN` might provide some speed improvements, but truthfully the above it pretty simple SQL. The last 2 statements (the `UPDATE`s) could only be improved by ensuring that the required indexes are on the table `GUID_ACTION`. What was your attempt to use a `JOIN`?

Comment: Alternatively, you could likely do the whole thing in a single `UPDATE`, without an `EXISTS`.

Comment: My first thought was to get rid of the subquery, and make a Join query of the 2 
tables.                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                         
SELECT *
FROM CUSTOMER_CARDNUMBER.GENERATED_CARDNUMBER, PROFILE.CARDNUMBER
INNER JOIN Profile ON CUSTOMER_CARDNUMBER.???; @Larnu

Comment: Time to stop using those old style joins; they were superseded 28 years ago! [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Could somebody show me an example of above, in a simpler better and maybe more modern way.. Can't seem to understand it, sorry pretty new with this. the tutorials are showing me the old way apparently ..

Comment: I somewhat doubt the tutorials are showing you the ANSI-89 syntax, like I said that was superseded 28 years ago, and hasn't been supported in SQL Server at all since 2012 (with it being deprecated in 2008). If so, then you must be reading was *really* old tutorials from the 90's. Have a read of anything more modern; though the above link shows you what a modern JOIN is.

Comment: @Larnu, When I would turn this script into a a single Update query, wouldn't I have to do two of them? and how what such a query look like? I feel kind of stuck. I would appreciate some extra help :s

Comment: What is this -> `FROM   CUSTOMER_CARDNUMBER WHERE CUSTOMER_CARDNUMBER = @GUID`? You have a table with the same name as a column in that same table? And let's post the primary and foreign keys (if any). Best would be to post DDL so everyone can understand the relationships between the tables and the primary and natural keys of your tables. And no - 2 databases are not involved here - at least not based on the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

``UPDATE GUID_ACTION
SET REVISION_STATUS =
CASE WHEN (0 < select count(*) from CUSTOMER_CARDNUMBERCUSTOMER_CARDNUMBER
inner join PROFILE
ON PROFILE.Cardnumber = CUSTOMER_CARDNUMBER.GENERATED_CARDNUMBER
AND PROFILE.Cardnumber = @GUID
)
THEN 'A'
ELSE 'F'
END;
,GUID_ACTION.REVISION_DATE_CREATED = GETDATE()
WHERE CUSTOMER_CARDNUMBER.GUID = @GUID;

This is a another more cleaner way, the query script with the subquery was difficult to understand with no insight of the tables or declared @GUID